# How to make an interpreter store variables

Tags: c, variables, interpreter

I’ve been trying to make a little programming language but I can’t figure out how to make my interpreter store and recall variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_VARIABLES 10

// Structure to store variables
struct Variable {
    char name[50];
    char value[256];
};

// Array to store variables
struct Variable variables[MAX_VARIABLES];
int variableCount = 0;

// Function to find a variable by name
struct Variable *findVariable(const char *name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < variableCount; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(variables[i].name, name) == 0) {
            return &variables[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL; // Variable not found
}

// Function to interpret commands
void interpretCommand(const char *command) {
    if (strncmp(command, "console:write->", 15) == 0) {
        // Extract the message within double quotes
        const char *messageStart = strchr(command, '"');
        const char *messageEnd = strrchr(command, '"');

        if (messageStart != NULL && messageEnd != NULL && messageStart < messageEnd) {
            // Print the message, replacing variables if present
            for (const char *p = messageStart + 1; p < messageEnd; ++p) {
                if (*p == '*') {
                    ++p; // Move past '*'
                    const char *varStart = p;
                    while (*p != '*' && p < messageEnd) {
                        ++p;
                    }

                    char varName[50];
                    strncpy(varName, varStart, p - varStart);
                    varName[p - varStart] = '\0';

                    struct Variable *variable = findVariable(varName);
                    if (variable != NULL) {
                        printf("%s", variable->value);
                    } else {
                        printf("Undefined variable: %s", varName);
                    }
                } else {
                    putchar(*p);
                }
            }
            putchar('\n');
        } else {
            printf("Invalid message format\n");
        }
    } else if (strncmp(command, "console:read->", 14) == 0) {
      // Extract the prompt within double quotes
      const char *promptStart = strchr(command, '"');
      const char *promptEnd = strrchr(command, '"');

      if (promptStart != NULL && promptEnd != NULL && promptStart < promptEnd) {
          // Print the prompt and read user input
          printf("%.*s", (int)(promptEnd - promptStart - 1), promptStart + 1);

          // Read user input
          char userInput[256]; // Adjust size as needed
          fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);

      } else {
          printf("Invalid prompt format\n");
      }
    } else {
        // Check if the command starts with "variableName->"
        char *arrow = strstr(command, "->");
        if (arrow != NULL) {
            *arrow = '\0'; // Separate variable name and value

            // Find or create a variable with the given name
            struct Variable *variable = findVariable(command);
            if (variable == NULL) {
                if (variableCount < MAX_VARIABLES) {
                    strcpy(variables[variableCount].name, command);
                    variable = &variables[variableCount++];
                } else {
                    printf("Maximum number of variables reached\n");
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Copy the value to the variable
            strcpy(variable->value, arrow + 2);
        } else {
            printf("Unknown command\n");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Open the file
    FILE *file = fopen("King.roar", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[256]; // Assuming a maximum line length of 255 characters

    // Read and interpret each line from the file
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        // Remove newline character if present
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        if (len > 0 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[len - 1] = '\0';
        }

        // Interpret the command
        interpretCommand(line);
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my sample code stored in **King.roar**:

```
console:read->"Enter your name: "->name
console:read->"Enter your age: "->age
console:write->"Hello *name*!"
console:write->"You are *age* years old!"
```

For some reason I only get undefined variable I don’t know if the data isn’t being stored or it’s the recall that’s not working

I tried looking up on the internet but I didn’t find anything about it. Thanks for helping !

Comment: Time to *debug* your program. Use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what actually happens.

Comment: On a different and unrelated note, [there are simpler ways to remove the newline from `fgets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code to store a value into a variable seems to be

```
variable_name->value
```

But in the file you seem to use a different syntax:

```
console:read->"Enter your name: "->name
```

It seems more consistent to use

```
value->variable_name
```

and use a *current value* that will be set by the console methods and other syntaxes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_VARIABLES 10

// Structure to store variables
struct Variable {
    char name[50];
    char value[256];
};

// Array to store variables
struct Variable variables[MAX_VARIABLES];
int variableCount = 0;

// Function to find a variable by name
struct Variable *findVariable(const char *name, size_t len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < variableCount; ++i) {
        if (memcmp(variables[i].name, name, len) == 0
        &&  variables[i].name[len] == '\0') {
            return &variables[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL; // Variable not found
}

void console_write(const char *s, size_t len) {
    // Print the message, replacing variables if present
    for (const char *p = s, *end = s + len; p < end; p++) {
        if (*p == '*' && ++p < end && *p != '*') {
            const char *varName = p;
            while (p < end && *p != '*') {
                ++p;
            }
            size_t nameLen = p - varName;
            struct Variable *variable = findVariable(varName, nameLen);
            if (variable != NULL) {
                printf("%s", variable->value);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Undefined variable: %.*s\n", (int)nameLen, varName);
            }
        } else {
            putchar(*p);
        }
    }
}

// Function to interpret commands
int interpretCommand(const char *line) {
    char current_value[250];

    *current_value = '\0';
    for (const char *command = line; *command;) {
        if (strncmp(command, "console:write->", 15) == 0) {
            // Extract the message within double quotes
            const char *messageStart = strchr(command, '"');
            const char *messageEnd = strrchr(command, '"');
            if (messageStart == NULL || messageEnd == NULL || messageStart >= messageEnd) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid message format\n");
                return 1;
            }
            console_write(messageStart + 1, messageEnd - messageStart - 1);
            putchar('\n');
            command = messageEnd + 1;
        } else
        if (strncmp(command, "console:read->", 14) == 0) {
            // Extract the prompt within double quotes
            const char *promptStart = strchr(command, '"');
            const char *promptEnd = strrchr(command, '"');
            if (promptStart == NULL || promptEnd == NULL || promptStart >= promptEnd) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid prompt format\n");
                return 1;
            }
            // Print the prompt and read user input
            console_write(promptStart + 1, promptEnd - promptStart - 1);
            // Read user input
            fgets(current_value, sizeof(current_value), stdin);
            size_t len = strlen(current_value);
            if (len > 0 && current_value[len - 1] == '\n')
                current_value[--len] = '\0';
            command = promptEnd + 1;
        } else
        if (!strncmp(command, "->", 2)) {
            // ->variableName
            const char *name = command + 2;
            size_t len = strlen(name);
            struct Variable *variable = findVariable(name, len);
            if (variable == NULL) {
                if (len >= sizeof(variable->name)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Variable name too long: %.*s\n", (int)len, name);
                    return 1;
                }
                if (variableCount >= MAX_VARIABLES) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Maximum number of variables reached\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                memcpy(variables[variableCount].name, name, len);
                variables[variableCount].name[len] = '\0';
                variable = &variables[variableCount++];
            }
            strcpy(variable->value, current_value);
            command = name + len;
        } else
        if (*command == '\"') {
            // string value
            const char *valueStart = command;
            const char *valueEnd = strrchr(command, '"');
            if (valueStart >= valueEnd) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unterminated value string: %s\n", command);
                return 1;
            }
            size_t len = valueEnd - valueStart - 1;
            if (len >= sizeof(current_value)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Value string too long: %.*s\n", (int)len + 1, valueStart);
                return 1;
            }
            memcpy(current_value, valueStart + 1, len);
            current_value[len] = '\0';
            command = valueEnd + 1;
        } else {
            char *arrow = strstr(command, "->");
            if (arrow != NULL) {
                size_t len = arrow - command;
                struct Variable *variable = findVariable(command, len);
                if (variable == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown variable: %.*s\n", (int)len, command);
                    return 1;
                }
                strcpy(current_value, variable->value);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown command: %s\n", command);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Open the file
    const char *filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "King.roar";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    char line[256]; // Assuming a maximum line length of 255 characters

    // Read and interpret each line from the file
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        // Remove newline character if present
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        if (len > 0 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[len - 1] = '\0';
        }

        // Interpret the command
        if (interpretCommand(line))
            break;
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried it).

According to your code you are checking for a variable by checking for

(variable-name)->

(you look for -> and chop the name off at the arrow). But your sample code uses

->(variable-name)

(->name, ->age), so chopping off at the arrow would result in an empty string being used as the variable name. Try printing out the name of the variable you end up with for storage, surrounded by * and * - I think you will end up with **!